# Cannot call methods on nvarchar

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have strange problem with simple SELECT statement, which I use in my asp.net application. I work with MSSQL 2008.

This statement works:

```
SelectSQL = "SELECT user_id, user_name, user_surname, user_code FROM Users WHERE user_group = '" + drop.SelectedItem.Value + "'";
```

however, this line throws "*Cannot call methods on nvarchar.*"

```
SelectSQL = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Equations.eq_id) AS pocet_prikladu, Users.user_name, User.user_surname FROM Users LEFT JOIN Equations ON (Users.user_id = Equations.eq_user_id) WHERE Users.user_code = '" + drop.SelectedItem.Value + "' GROUP BY Users.user_id, Users.user_name, User.user_surname ";
```

here is more code, it stops at the last line

```
public void FillTable(Table tab, DropDownList drop)     //naplneni tabulky
    {
        SqlConnection pripojeni = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        string SelectSQL = "";
        if (action == "groups")
        {
            SelectSQL = "SELECT user_id, user_name, user_surname, user_code FROM Users WHERE user_group = '" + drop.SelectedItem.Value + "'";
        }
        else
        {
            SelectSQL = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Equations.eq_id) AS pocet_prikladu, Users.user_name, User.user_surname FROM Users LEFT JOIN Equations ON (Users.user_id = Equations.eq_user_id) WHERE Users.user_code = '" + drop.SelectedItem.Value + "' GROUP BY Users.user_id, Users.user_name, User.user_surname ";
        }
        try
        {
            SqlCommand prikaz = new SqlCommand(SelectSQL, pripojeni);
            pripojeni.Open();
            SqlDataReader vysledky = prikaz.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Can you please post a more complete code sample, including how you're sending the query into SQL?

Comment: You have a typo - User.user_surname should be Users.user_surname

Comment: Thanks Chris. It works now. Another wasted hour spent by finding solution :D

Comment: Someone down voted you so I set you back up as they leave a comment explaining it. We can all make a typo so seemed harsh.

Comment: haha, I was having this same error, but dismissed the solution since it was just a typo. But then, I looked through my query again, and as it turns out, I had also left off an 's' in "users". I never would have checked for misspellings were it not for this post. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

You may need to delimit user as [user]. User is a reserved keyword.

So [User].user_surname etc

Also as Chris says typo change User.user_surname to Users.user_surname.

I'd guess the undelimited [User] issue is causing the strange error

Comment: You aren't using user. You are using users so looks like a typo in second one. Change it to users

Comment: I still think you got that error as it was undelimited. Change it to another misspelling and you will probably get a different error. I could be wrong. I often am! :)